# Picking cards and get consecutive numbers and different suits

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Picking 4 cards in a 48 cards deck (12 of each suit). Which is the probability of get the 4 cards with different suits and consecutive numbers?

The 4 cards are picked at the same time with no replacement.

Comment: How many sets of $4$ cards satisfy the requirements?  How many ways are there to pick $4$ cards?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What aspect are you finding difficult?

Comment: I don't really know how to count the sets that satisfy the requirements. I mean, The first card doesn't matter which suit is. The second ones is 3/4, the third 2/4 and the last one 1/4.But to get consecutive numbers... Pick consecutive could be 1-4-2-3, 4-5-7-6... and I don't know how to count them.

Comment: Are the cards in a suit numbered from 1 to 12?

Comment: Yes, cards are numered

Answer (score 0):

I think I could solve it $90$%

Ways to pick 4 cards: $\binom{48}{4}$

Ways to pick 1 card of each suit: $\binom{12}{1}^4 = 12^4$

The groups that can be consecutive are from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $\{9,10,11,12\}$, a total of $9$ groups.
The ways to pick these groups are $9·4^4$

But now my problem is how to calculate the probability of "4 cards with different suits and consecutive numbers", I mean... how to order these numbers.

I tried (it's wrong) $\frac{12^4·9·4^4}{\binom{48}{4}}$ but it's $>1$ so it isn't a probability.